# XA Aware Data Structures (Non Database)

Tags: java, data-structures, transactions, xa

**Bit of Background:** I've run into a problem and the more I dig into it the more XA seems like the right solution.  I have a "cache" which is basically an in memory data structure (tree esq.) used to hold some processed information.  Using `Spring`, we have our Database set and using `@Transactional` which has been working like a charm.  For large complex business logic, ACID holds true in our DB and everything is great.  The problem is our data structure in memory is NOT `Transactional` by design.

I've learned the differences between local and global transactions, and the global variety seems to be what I need.  As we are performing logic, we use the "cache structure" as a way to inform decisions we make.  These changes then need to propagate to the DB, but if anything needs to rollback the DB does and the "cache" doesn't.

**Question** Is the `javax.transaction.xa.XAResource` interface what is needed for my custom data structure?  Am I right in understanding XA, but not understanding its use in a non database/JMS/etc. setting but something a lot simpler?  I don't mind putting in the work to basically wrap my structure and have it implement, but I am not sure if it will achieve the goal I am really looking for.

TLDR: Is implementing `javax.transaction.xa.XAResource` doable for simpler data structures not involving complex DBs, or is there something I am not understanding with `JTA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAResource is not db specific and can be implemented over other types of resource manager. The most common is message queue systems (e.g. JMS), but many cache/datagrid products also support transactional usage, see e.g.

http://infinispan.org/docs/9.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#transactions

Note that depending on your requirements, a cache layer may behave as a Synchronization rather than an XAResource. Some ORM systems work that way to allow e.g. pre-commit session flushing.

If you don't need recovery, XAResource is a relatively straightforward interface to implement, BUT only if your datasource is already equipped to handle the underlying properties (atomicity, consistency and isolation). For example, what does a cache read or write look like in your API? If it has no notion of transaction context in which it operates on the cache structure, then you have a problem that you're going to have to fix before looking at XA.